# Шаблоны. Специализация

Tags: c++

Верные ли утверждения:
1. Полная специализация есть для функций и классов
2. Частичная специализация есть исключительно для классов
3. Для функций роль частичной специализации выполняет механизм перегрузки
4. Частичная специализация для классов есть аналогия перегрузки для функций

Comment: А у вас какие-нибудь версии есть?

Comment: Это мои версии) хочу узнать их правоту

Comment: Хотелось бы ваши версии по поводу верности этих утверждений, а то сейчас они похожи на кусок какого-то теста, который вы предлагаете выполнить за вас.

Comment: а ещё неплохо было бы пояснить, что такое «специализация»...

Comment: Ну так как я автор этих утверждений, то значит я их всех считаю верными

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 и 2 - верно. 3 и 4 - слишком нечеткие формулировки, чтобы можно было дать однозначные ответы. По-видимому, авторами этих вопросов подразумевалось "да" в качестве правильного ответа, но если задаться целью, то можно привести контрпримеры.

Для вопроса 3: перегрузка и специализация - фундаментально разные по своей сути механизмы. Я не вижу причин стараться привести их к некоему "общему знаменателю".

Перегрузка функций (или шаблонов функций) создает набор *равноправных* функций (или шаблонов функций), которые все одновременно и равноправно участвуют в процессе *разрешения перегрузки* (overload resolution). Среди них выбирается единственный лучший кандидат, если таковой удается выбрать.

Специализация шаблонов функций ведет себя совсем по-другому. Специализации (как полные, так и частичные) являются "гражданами второго сорта" и изначально не допускаются до overload resolution. Их всех там представляет лишь главный (неспециализированный)  шаблон. И только если главный шаблон победит, в рассмотрение принимаются его специализации.

Для вопроса 4: тут уж я совсем не вижу зачем пытаться представить специализацию классов как аналог перегрузки функций. Чисто неформально, для улучшения понимания, такое утверждение можно сделать. Но вот вопроса с ответом "да/нет" тут никак не получается. Возможность дедукции аргументов шаблона класса в С++17 действительно усиливает внешнее сходство шаблонов классов с шаблонами функцией, но это сходство все равно лишь поверхностно.

Comment: Если рассматривать шаблонный класс как метафункцию, специализация является аналогом перегрузки. А вот вывод аргументов шаблона - это уже из другой оперы, даже если это вывод из аргументов конструктора.